# Сборщик мусора убьет объект класса где таймер отрабатывает одно условие?

Tags: c#, clr

Сборщик мусора убьет объект класса где таймер отрабатывает одно условие? Я хочу что бы условие отрабатывалось раз в сутки, что-то нужно добавить в метод\класс?

```
    Starter startSomeMethod;
    private int _hour { get; set; }
    private int _minute { get; set; }
    private Timer _timer;
    private object _lockThis;

    public  Updater(Starter start, int hour, int minutes)
    {
        _hour = hour;
        _minute = minutes;
        startSomeMethod = start;
        if (_lockThis != null)
            return;
        _lockThis = new object();
        _timer = new Timer(new TimerCallback(OnTimedEvent), null, 0, 45000);
    }

    private void OnTimedEvent(object obj)
    {
        lock (_lockThis)
        {
            DateTime dd = DateTime.Now;
            if (dd.Hour == _hour && dd.Minute == _minute)
            {
              startSomeMethod();   
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Извиняюсь, ввел правку

Answer (score 1):

Если ваш класс, который содержит `_timer`, не умрёт, то он будет содержать ссылку, которая будет держать ваш таймер «на плаву».

Поэтому вам нужно позаботиться о том, чтобы объект, содержащий ссылку, не умер.

[MSDN подчёркивает](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_4) (привожу английский текст, т. к. русский перевод в MSDN неточен):

> As long as you are using a `Timer`, you must keep a reference to it. As with any managed object, a `Timer` is subject to garbage collection when there are no references to it. The fact that a Timer is still active does not prevent it from being collected.

то есть

> Вы обязаны держать живую ссылку на таймер пока вы используете его. Как и любой управляемый объект, таймер, на которого не останется ссылок, может быть убран сборщиком мусора. То, что таймер всё ещё активен, не предотвращает сборку его сборщиком мусора.

---

Если заглянуть в исходник [текущей имплементации таймера](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/timer.cs,051a39d380760b26), можно увидеть, что в случае, когда вы конструируете таймер с одним лишь callback'ом, в [глобальную очередь](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/timer.cs,d4834e437a51e6dd) [уходит](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/timer.cs,2f09e137537660b3) [ссылка на сам таймер](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/timer.cs,872). А значит, таймер в этом случае будет держать себя в памяти сам. Но это поведение не гарантировано документацией, и в предыдущих версиях .NET таймер вёл себя [по-другому](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4962172/276994). И скорее всего в будущем тоже. Поэтому полагаться на это просто опасно, полагайтесь лучше на документацию.

Ну и кроме того, вы используете другой конструктор.

Comment: Только что хотел написать то же самое, что написал PetSerAl

Comment: @PetSerAl: В случае, о котором я говорю, ссылка на Timer уходит как state. (Перепроверю.)

Comment: @VladD Да, Вы правы.

Comment: @VladD ссылка на этот класс хранится в Main методе.

Comment: @ВасилийСтаровойтов: Ну, значит сборщик мусора ваш таймер не соберёт — по крайней мере если ваш `Main` не завершится до срабатывания таймера.